# 70s movie ends with a train/car crash

Tags: identify-this-movie

I saw it on TV in the 80s, as best as I can recall it was produced in the 70s. I have no idea about title, actors, or plot, but I do remember the ending:

A man and a woman were driving on country roads, trying to evade the police. Possibly their goal was to cross the county line. They had a police scanner and were listening to the sheriff radio instructions to his deputies.

The couple was getting more and more boxed in until one deputy radioed back that he was nowhere near where he was told to be. The couple then realized that the sheriff was bluffing positions/manpower, so they happily made a break for it.

They crossed a railroad track and were suddenly hit by a train. Roll credits.

Does anyone know this movie?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sounds like [Dirty Mary, Crazy Larry](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0071424/).

Here is a summary written by Larry Rayder:

> Larry and Deke are a small time car racing duo who rob a grocery store, and plan to use the proceeds to buy an expensive race car in order to win more races and break in to the professional NASCAR circuit. Their escape with the loot does not go as smoothly as planned when Larry's one night stand, Mary, tags along for the ride. One step ahead of an obsessed Sheriff, they manage to evade several police cruisers, a high-performance police interceptor, and even a helicopter, in their 1969 Dodge Charger R/T. Almost...

It's the "Almost..." that you are remembering. As Crazy Larry realizes they are actually in the clear, all three riders celebrate as he speeds away down a highway. They are just about to cross an uncontrolled train track crossing, when Dirty Mary see's the on-coming train. Their car is obliterated in the impact.

Comment: Yes, definitely sounds like it. The ending is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NnCF4kJAzIw).

Comment: I swear I was just thinking about this movie this morning. Amazing coincidence. Gotta watch it.

Comment: Yep, that looks right. Awesome, thank you everyone. I'll have to watch it again.

Comment: yes it is dirty mary crazy larry, seen about 3 times and never forgot it. the ending kinda tripped me out because at the time i was about 13,good movie,havent seen it in a while but would like to again